# How to call a Python function with vanilla Javascript in a Django app

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on a Django app and I am trying to call a Python function in `views.py` on a button click. I am trying to call this function using vanilla JavaScript if possible, because I am very unfamiliar with JavaScript and would like to try to keep things simple. The idea would be to display the text returned by the `hello()` function by using JavaScript to create a new `div` after the button is clicked. I believe I can do that part, but I have not been able to find any information on calling the Python function. I have the JavaScript function alerting with the text for now. Here is a sample of my code so far:

./views.py

```
def hello():
  return "Hello world"
```

./static/js/index.js

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', printHello);

function printHello() {
  var text = // call Python function
  alert(text);
};
```

Comment: You can't do that. What you can do in javascript is create a fetch request to your view that has the response "Hellow World"

Comment: Using the "fetch ... .then" syntax?

Comment: Yes, that's basically for calling URLs in javascript.

Comment: Okay, so I would fetch the view url and in the .then block I would call the Python function?

Comment: The URL is the python view function, the then block contains the response of your view which would be "Hello World"

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as this.

views.py

```py
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('Hello/', views.hello, name='hello')
]
```

javascript

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/Hello')
  .then(data => console.log(data)); //Hello World
```